# Length mismatch while applying a logic to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to change to uppercase of alternate column names of a Dataframe having 6 columns.

input :

```
df.columns[::2].str.upper()
```

Output :

```
Index(['FIRST_NAME', 'AGE_VALUE', 'MOB_#'], dtype='object')
```

Now i want to apply this to Dataframe.

input : `df.columns= df.columns[::2].str.upper()`

> ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 6 elements, new values have 3 elements

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: please be more specific what you are trying to do. Do you want to upper columns names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

```py
df
   a  b  c  d  e  f
0  a  b  c  d  e  f
column_names = dict(zip(df.columns[::2], df.columns[::2].str.upper()))
column_names
{'a': 'A', 'c': 'C', 'e': 'E'}

df = df.rename(columns=column_names)
df
   A  b  C  d  E  f
0  a  b  c  d  e  f
```